# .map() is storing unwanted undefined values into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

Simple array declaration:

```
let sodas = ["Sprite", "Coke", "Mountain Dew", "Dr. Pepper", "Sunkist"];
```

I want to use `.map()` function to create a new array containing sodas only owned by the CocaCola Company, and then display this new array in the console -

```
let cocacola_sodas = sodas.map(soda => {
  if ((soda == "Coke") || (soda == "Sprite")) {
    return soda;
  }
})

console.log(cocacola_sodas);
```

This code seems to work, though I'm not sure why it is returning 5 new elements into `cocacola_sodas` array when only 2 of them should be returned (coke and sprite). The array will display `["Sprite", "Coke", undefined, undefined, undefined]`. Why is it returning undefined values?

Comment: Because that's what the mapped function returns for those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter instead of map. It was made or use in situations like this. As pointed by other answers map will always return the same number of elements as present in the input array

```js
let sodas = ["Sprite", "Coke", "Mountain Dew", "Dr. Pepper", "Sunkist"];

let cocacola_sodas = sodas.filter(soda => {
  if ((soda == "Coke") || (soda == "Sprite")) {
    return soda;
  }
})
console.log(cocacola_sodas);
```

Answer (score 0):

@awoldt, to help you understand what is actually happening, `Array.prototype.map` will always return the same number of elements from the input array to a new array.

so best way to think about it is you give map an array with x elements, regardless of what you do to those elements inside the block you pass to map, it will always return X # of elements in the new array.

As was suggested, something like filter/reduce will return a new array with just the elements that meet the criteria you set out int he block passed to those helpers

you can read more about map and all the Array.prototype.methods at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on @ellipsis answer:
The reason filter is better here is because it is generating a new array of items not filtered out of the original array.

The reason map is giving you the results you see are because it's not filtering, but changing each element and giving it to the result array. I think a code example would help to clarify.

Map might look something like this under the hood:

```
var array = ['one', 'two', three];
var mapFunc = function(item) {
    if(item == 'two')
        return item;
};
var mappedArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    mappedArray.push(mapFunc(array[i]));
```

Obviously the above is simplified to be clear, but as you can see the mapped array will have as many items in it as the original array. Since you return nothing in the case item doesn't equal two then you return `undefined` hence why you have the extra items in your example.

Answer (score -1):

The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
let sodas = ["Sprite", "Coke", "Mountain Dew", "Dr. Pepper", "Sunkist"];

let cocaCola = ["Coke","Sprite"];

let cocacola_sodas = sodas.filter(soda => cocaCola.includes(soda))

console.log(cocacola_sodas);
```